# Searching in List of Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, search

I have a list of dictionaries. How do I count the number of elements with **'label' : 'car'** ?

Also how do I create a completely new list with all the elements that have **'label' : 'car'** ?

```
result = [{'bottomright': {'x': 434, 'y': 102},
  'confidence': 0.3357535,
  'label': 'car',
  'topleft': {'x': 418, 'y': 88}},
 {'bottomright': {'x': 621, 'y': 120},
  'confidence': 0.55622935,
  'label': 'cup',
  'topleft': {'x': 580, 'y': 106}},
 {'bottomright': {'x': 136, 'y': 201},
  'confidence': 0.32227623,
  'label': 'truck',
  'topleft': {'x': 77, 'y': 166}},
 {'bottomright': {'x': 229, 'y': 235},
  'confidence': 0.3240861,
  'label': 'car',
  'topleft': {'x': 184, 'y': 198}},
 {'bottomright': {'x': 281, 'y': 265},
  'confidence': 0.63466769,
  'label': 'person',
  'topleft': {'x': 226, 'y': 220}},
 {'bottomright': {'x': 204, 'y': 286},
  'confidence': 0.54358166,
  'label': 'car',
  'topleft': {'x': 141, 'y': 233}},
 {'bottomright': {'x': 251, 'y': 331},
  'confidence': 0.70285547,
  'label': 'car',
  'topleft': {'x': 182, 'y': 253}},
 {'bottomright': {'x': 432, 'y': 361},
  'confidence': 0.74345809,
  'label': 'surfboard',
  'topleft': {'x': 370, 'y': 277}}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try filter function:

```
len(list(filter(lambda dic: dic['label'] == 'car', result)))
```

To create a completely new list, do:

```
list(filter(lambda dic: dic['label'] == 'car', result))
```

Remember to cast a `list` converter in front, since `filter` would return a 'filter object' itself.

Answer (score 1):

try following code:

```
include_label_list = [i for i in result if i.get('label') == 'car']
counter = len(include_label_list)
```

You got a new list with only have label with car, and your counter of this list should be the length of this new list!